# Should I create new table for every consistent data set or one systemCodes table?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Should I create new table for every consistent data set or one system--codes table WHEN using Microsoft Entity framework 6 ?

I mean by the "consistent data set" are like:

```
    +Agent (Table)
    -Id
    -Name
    -Status (consistent data = available | busy | unavailable)
    -Type   (consistent data = reception | delivery | driver)
    -Gender (consistent data = male | female)
    -AddressId

    +Address (Table)
    -Id
    -Description
    -Longitude
    -Latitude
    -City (consistent data = [ .... any city .... ])
    -State (consistent data = [ .... any state.... ])
```

My question is should i Have a table for each of Status, Type, Gender,...etc and link them to the "Agent" table using foreign keys and navigational properties ?
OR just make one table like this :

```
+SystemCodeTable
-CodeId
-CodeParentId
-NameAr
-NameEn
-Description
```

and save all my consistent data into it and then assign the CodeId to the "Status", "Type", "Gender", ...etc columns ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think For 
Status and Type - better you create StatusMaster and TypeMaster resp.

StatusMaster  (StatusID)0 - Available
              1 - Busy  2- Unavailable  and Use StatusID in Agent Table same you can create for TypeMaster. and for Gender you can directly use 'M' and 'F' or 'Male' and 'Female' as it is in Agent table.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, Should i link these new tables (status, type) with the "Agent" table ?
I'm using ASP.NET with Entity framework where doing that gives me an advantage in code and simplifies the queries and by doing that i want get all the employers with status available from both sides (querying through Status entity or through Agent entity with give the same results)

Comment: Also i hope you can explain why it is better for me to create separate tables for each set of consistent data instead of using one tables that holds all the codes-names combinations for the the consistent data like:
CodeId | Name >> 1, available || 2, busy || 3,unavailable || 4,reception || 5,delivery || 6, driver || ...etc

Comment: Hi, Yes you link that table(Status,Type) with primary key and foreign key in Agent Table.

Comment: The Reason behind this table separate is we create master table Like StatusMaster to identify 1 is for Available, 2 is for Busy as so on...., So in future if you want add or update the status or Type you can do it in master table no need to change in agent table. Hope you understand....